# Highcharts: How to ignore styling from title string

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Lets say I have a string of

```
var inputTitle = 'style="text-decoration:underline; color:#f00;"'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/Ewk3M/

How do I make it just render the text, but not the style?

Can't just use escape(), highcharts's HTML parser is not a full HTML parser and it only understands some html entities, and the result would be "style%3D%22text-d ...", which is not pretty...

Comment: What is the purpose of using that solution?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan, above is not the solution... Basically I do not want the user to be able to alter the css when I'm just asking for the text.. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/UM3nE/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported it to our developers as possibly bug https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2755 so please stay on track with github thread.